# Several devices in Device Manager have Code 3 error 'bis win7 64'

Tags: windows-7, drivers, device-manager

I'm having the same problems as in question "Several devices in Device Manager have Code 3 error" but with Win 7 64 bits Family Premium and would appreciate if somebody could tell me if the given answer works for 64 versions.Many thanks and regards from Switzerland.
wothan